# get Exception when use webservice(AXIS2)

Tags: apache-axis

I use axis2 and tomcat to develop my webservices which is used to search my system with Lucene.
I write the server class and test it, and then deploy it with "Axis2 Service Archiver". 
There are 2 method in the webservices. I user brower to test it. 
[http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/eBook/plus?x=1.1&y=2.2]
This simple method(PLUS) work well, and return 3.3.
But the another one(working with lucene) return some Exception:
    
    
    Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec
    
    
I don't know what make this problem. can someone help? Thanks a lot.
**The error message below:**

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:210)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
 at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:273)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
 at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
 ... 25 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec
 at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:299)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:56)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:783)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:52)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:65)
 at ns.eBook.Search.process2(Search.java:52)
 ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slove the problem.
After trying many way,I got the point.
I put every jar files(lucene) using in the webservices into "WEB-INF\lib", and it work. 
Thank goodness.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Axis2 and I put all the Axis2 jar files in `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder in my Eclipse project.